# Show that $ f(u) = u^{-2}(e^u - u- 1) $ is a nondecreasing function of $u$ for $u > 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis

Apparently simple inequality on functions in the proof of Bennett's inequality.

Show that
$$
f(u) = u^{-2}(e^u - u- 1) 
$$
is a nondecreasing function of $u$ for $u > 0$.

---

My research:

Derivating gives 
$$
f'(u) = \frac{(e^u -1) u^2 - 2u (e^u - u -1)}{u^4}  = \frac{e^u (u-2) + (u+2)}{u^3}
$$
Therefore it suffices to show that the denominator is positive.

For $u \ge  2$, $e^u > 1$ implies $e^u(u-2) \ge (u-2)$ which gives the result.

However, for $u < 2$, one might want to derivate again to find the minimum of the denominator, which satisfies $e^u (u-1) + 1 = 0$. It gives an expression of $e^u u $ but I still have to compare $u$ and $e^u$, and can't conclude.

Comment: Note that $$e^u = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{u^n}{n!}.$$ A simple power series calculation makes it obvious.

Comment: I suspect OP is looking for a proof without the power series representation of the exponential function

Comment: No using power series is fine, I'm trying it right now.

Comment: For $0<u<2$ you want to show that $e^u(2-u) < u+2$, which it clearly is since $2-u$ is negative.

Comment: You made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1+u$ is the first two terms of the series expansion of $e^u$, so by inspection $e^u-u-1$ expands to ${u^2\over 2}+{u^3\over 6}+{u^4\over 24}+\ldots$. That times $u^{-2}$ is ${1\over 2}+{u\over 6}+{u^2\over 24}+\ldots$, which is obviously non-decreasing. In fact it is always increasing with increasing slope for $u>0$, with an initial slope of $1\over 6$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(u)=e^u(u-1)$ for $u\ge 0$.

$$g'(u)=ue^u\ge 0$$

So $g$ is increasing and $g(u)\ge g(0)=-1$ for all $u\ge0$.

Let $h(u)=e^u(u-2)+u+2$ for $u\ge 0$.

$$h'(u)=e^u(u-1)+1\ge0$$

So $h$ is increasing and $h(u)\ge h(0)=0$ for all $u\ge0$.

Therefore, $f'(u)\ge0$ for all $u\ge0$.